# CSS2 Multi Classing

Tags: html, css, class

I have the following HTML:

```
<DIV class="foo bar"></DIV>
```

I'm trying to create a CSS class declaration that matches said element. Looking through the [specs on section 8.2.3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html), I imagine this should've work:

```
DIV.foo.bar { border-color: black; }
```

But I've tested on IE and Safari, both doesn't affect the element. Any tricks how to make this work?

Comment: The selector is correct.  Are you expecting it to look different? div elements have block display by default.

Comment: @p00ya: modified the question to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Which version of IE are you using?

Comment: @Rahul, IE8 on IE8 standards mode.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the use case that would demand this. Do you want to have foo be one style, bar be another, and foo AND bar be a third, or does this object just happen to have both classes for another reason (javascript etc) and you want to target it explicitly?

Comment: I consider your question to have been answered, but on a separate note you don't need to always specify the element name in your CSS rule unless you have specifically different styles applying to different elements with the same class.

Removing that level of specificness will speed up CSS rendering time.

Comment: @Will Yes, I just tried taking example from the spec since it doesn't seem to work on my original code. Must've been misspeling somewhere.

Comment: @Nate "foo" and "foo and bar".

Comment: In that case, yes, I think Rahul answered the question as far as compliance on newer browsers. But for IE6 (assuming you need to support it) you can probably have a situation where you assign "bar foo" on the element that needs both, to differentiate it from "foo", because it'll pick up the first class.

Comment: This is irrelevant to your question, but it's an (X)HTML style thing: tags (like div) should always be lowercase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's because you're specifying "border-color: black" without a border-width or border-style. Try setting "border: solid 1px black" and see if that works.

Comment: hmm.. yes, apparently it worked for DIV. Let me check the question again.

Answer (score 5):

There are three issues here potentially.

**1. Is your expression and HTML correct?**

Your div doesn't have a border width (from what you've posted) so you might not get a border. Try:

```
<div class="foo bar"></div>
```

with

```
div.foo.bar { border: 1px solid black; }
```

**2. Does you div have any height?**

Your div (based on what you've posted) has no height. Now on some browsers that'll render as a solid line of the border thickness. Depending on neighbouring elements and border collapse settings (particularly on Firefox more than IE/Safari though), that border may disappear in some circumstances.

**3. IE6 doesn't support multiple class selectors correctly**

Multiple class selector does not work (correctly) in IE6. See [multiple classes](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multipleclasses.html) and the [browser support table](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html).

Usually the trick here is to nest the divs:

```
<div class="foo"><div class="bar"></div></div>
```

and then of course:

```
div.foo div.bar { ... }
```

Not the same thing obviously but you don't have much choice. The other alternative is to combine the classes manually:

```
div.foo { background: red; }
div.bar { border: 1px solid black; }
div.foobar { background: red; border: 1px solid black; }

<div class="foobar"></div>
```

Again, far from ideal. But there's only so much you can do on IE6.

Comment: Nope, there's a reason why both classes need to be there.

Comment: For that matter, according to cletus' "browser support table" link, Safari should support what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

IE6 [doesn't support](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) selectors with multiple classes on the same element. The [IE-7.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) script supposedly fixes that.

Your selector should work fine in IE7+ and recent versions of Safari.

Comment: The details of the question changed a bit since I started typing this answer. The CSS selector 'DIV.foo.bar' should work with the HTML '<DIV class="foo bar"></DIV>'.

Comment: Thanks for the info on IE6 compatibility, will need to think something else than this then.

Comment: -1: IE6 does support multiple classes on the same element in Standards Mode. I use it a lot on http://www.abcavendre.com without any problems.

Comment: **Addition:** It even supports it in Quirks.

Comment: Okay, I've done some more research. IE6 would indeed apply the styles to <div class="foo bar"></div>. But it would also apply to <div class="bar">, so what use is that?